# How to download this SVN with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hi how do I download this:

[ps2sdk](http://svn.ps2dev.org/listing.php?repname=ps2&path=/trunk/ps2sdk/&#a172abc4ccbd38b9cb3693f32e25ca436)

with TortoiseSVN ? Do you know the SVN link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the sources and the pre-built libraries and tools here http://lukasz.dk/files/ps2sdk. According to this site http://lukasz.dk/2010/09/09/ps2dev-org-mirrors/, the ps2dev.org site has been down lately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a git repository https://github.com/ps2dev/ps2sdk.